# Resolving dependency issues during installation with apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management

I wanted to simply update rvm with ruby 2.3:

```
rvm install ruby-2.3.0
```

But I got some dependency issues:

```
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_remove libssl-dev',
please read /home/john/.rvm/log/1568069021_ruby-2.3.0/package_remove_libssl-dev.log
```

The log file informed me the issue was related to mariadb:

```
tail -n 100 /home/john/.rvm/log/1568069021_ruby-2.3.0/package_remove_libssl-dev.log

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 1:10.1.41+maria-1~bionic) but 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to let it resolve the dependency issue but it did not work out:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb containing mariadb-server-core-10.1:
 mariadb-server-10.1 conflicts with mysql-server-core-5.5
  mariadb-server-core-10.1 provides mysql-server-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-server-core-10.1
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-core-10.1:
 mariadb-client-10.1 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5
  mariadb-client-core-10.1 provides mysql-client-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-core-10.1
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-10.1:
 mariadb-client-core-10.1 conflicts with mysql-client-5.5
  mariadb-client-10.1 provides mysql-client-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried to manually remove mariadb, but still the dependency error occurs:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server-core-10.1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 1:10.1.41+maria-1~bionic) but 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server-10.1 : Depends: mariadb-server-core-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is my local machine, so I don't remind removing things. But I can't install ruby 2.3 or remove mariadb in order to install ruby 2.3. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I had some versions of MariaDB and some versions of MySQL installed and Ubuntu could no longer decipher all this. Perhaps I had an older version of a MySQL database and trying to run a newer version of the server. It was not exactly clear as to the confusion the server was going through. But to address the situation, I deleted literally everything MySQL:

```
PKGS="mysql-server mariadb-client mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-common"
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt remove $PKGS
sudo apt purge $PKGS
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/ 
sudo updatedb
locate mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
 sudo rm -rf /etc/default/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service
sudo rm -rf /home/dan/.mysql_history
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_amd64.deb
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient20_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
 sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_1%3a10.1.41+maria-1~bionic_all.deb
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
 sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysqld
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysql.service
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysqld.service
```

At this point, there was no trace of MariaDB or MySQL on my system. Now I was able to install MariaDB 10.1 clean:

```
$ apt-cache policy software-properties-common
software-properties-common:
  Installed: 0.96.24.32.11
```

MariaDB repository public key used by the package management system:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
```

add MariaDB 10.1 repository to your Ubuntu:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu '$(lsb_release -cs)' main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB101.list"
```

Then install mariadb:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

--- Mac OSX Solution ---

So my previous answer was in regards to Linux, particularly, Ubuntu. For sake of completeness for anyone enduring mysql/mariadb compatibility issues, I provide the OSX solution as well:

```
$ brew list --versions mariadb
mariadb 10.3.12

$ brew uninstall mariadb
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.3.12... (658 files, 174.4MB)

$ brew doctor

$ brew cleanup # should you have some broken symlinks somewhere

$ brew info mariadb
Conflicts with:
  mariadb-connector-c  
  mysql 
  mytop  
  percona-server

$ brew list --versions mariadb-connector-c 
$ brew list --versions mysql
$ brew list --versions mytop
$ brew list --versions percona-server

$ brew search mariadb
mariadb@10.1 mariadb@10.2 mariadb@10.3
```

Do NOT install mariadb@10.1 yet! Even after you uninstall previous installs, brew leaves the datadir alone during the next installation to make sure it doesn’t delete user-generated data. If you’re sure that you have no important data in your MySQL database on this machine (from either a Homebrew-installed or other MySQL installation), then yes, go ahead uninstall both the datadir and my.cnf config:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
rmdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.default
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.default.default
```

Now you can install the older version:

```
$ brew install mariadb@10.1  


A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

mariadb@10.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have mariadb@10.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find mariadb@10.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/include"

For pkg-config to find mariadb@10.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/share/pkgconfig"


To have launchd start mariadb@10.1 now and restart at login:
  brew services start mariadb@10.1
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin/mysql.server start
```

Read the closing notes from the install! you will need to add the $PATH to mariadb@10.1 to your .bash_profile (if that is the one that is loaded on shell init).